# How to use VBA variable for IN 'SourceDB' clause of MS-ACCESS query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to pass a vba string variable to an IN clause of a SQL statement in the query builder view.

the string is created by the following function:

```
Public Function GetBackEnd()
    If Len(GetBackEnd) = 0 Then GetBackEnd = BackEnd
End Function
```

backend itself is derived from a dropdown box in  userform, there are two entries in a table with two different addresses, one each for the live and developement DB's. The dropdown box sets the "environment" variable upon selection.

```
Property Get BackEnd() As String
    Select Case Environment
        Case Is = "Development"
            BackEnd = DLookup("VariableValue", "Globals", "Variable= 'TestEnvironment'")
        Case Else
            BackEnd = DLookup("VariableValue", "Globals", "Variable= 'Backend'")
    End Select
End Property
```

I have tried a couple of variations on the following but get an error each time.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName IN 'GetBackEnd()';
```

I imagine its something simple but after staring at this for so long Ijust can't see it.

thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the function.  What is `BackEnd`?

Comment: I have update the original post with the functions for backend.

Comment: You cant do that. Try to build the SQL string and then update the `.SQL` property of the query in VBA.

Comment: But since you pass a single string, why do you need the IN?

Comment: because IN is telling the query which database to execute the select statement, it could be one of two depending on the value of Backend. i.e. Select * from table in LiveDB, or Select * From table in DevelopmentDB. Structurally both db's are identical, the Dev DB is a couple of weeks older in terms of data content and has any identifiable infomation (names, addresses etc) anomolised for development/training etc.

Comment: Unless Access has very weird SQL syntax, `IN` doesn't select which database you connect to. There is some earlier point in your code where you connect to your database.

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen: It's a feature. :) -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/in-clause-microsoft-access-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can do what you want - use a function to provide parameter strings.

```vb
Public Function GetName() As String
    GetName = "foo"
End Function
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM bar WHERE floo = GetName()
```

But in some parts / cases, you can't use variables. Both `IN` clauses are among them.

These won't work:

```vb
GetInList = "'x', 'y', 'z'"
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM bar WHERE floo IN (GetInList())
```

and your use-case is not possible either:

```vb
GetDbPath = "C:\path\myDb.accdb"
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM bar IN GetDbPath()
```

You will have to construct the whole SQL on the fly:

```vb
Db.QueryDefs("myQuery").SQL = "SELECT * FROM TableName IN '" & GetBackEnd() & "'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i'll go down that route instead

Answer (score 0):

Missing WHERE clause in SQL query? Let's say

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName 
WHERE Name = GetBackEnd;
```

Comment: wouldn't that just be looking for a field Name within TableName? the IN clause is specifying which database the table TableName resides in.

Comment: Try to set the query string into some variable and then execute entire string query, so You will be able to debug code much deeper.

Comment: I have used this syntax in exsisting queries built and executed from the VBA environment successfully. This is the first time i'm trying to bring a VBA variable into the query builder.