# MS Access query with user function criteria stops working on odbc data

Tags: oracle, function, ms-access, odbc

I am working in the MS Access query builder.  I'm using a user-defined function to return a bracketed group of characters to search for.  For example, the criteria line is

```
Like Tcode()
```

and the function Tcode() is

```
Function Tcode() As String
Tcode = "[AC]"
End Function
```

If I create a local table of data with 3 single-character rows of data

```
A
B
C
```

and run a query on that column with this criteria, I get just the rows of A and C, as desired.  If I run it with the criteria of

```
Like "[AC]"
```

I also get just the rows of A and C, as desired.  The problem comes in when I run a query against an ODBC   Oracle table we have.  If I use the criteria of Like "[AC]" then I get results of A and C.  If I use the criteria of like Tcode() then I get no results.  I have tried several variations on the return value of Tcode without success:

Tcode returns [AC]  No results

Tcode returns "[AC]" No results

Tcode returns [[AC]] No results

Tcode returns [A]  No results

Tcode returns A  Results in all rows with A

I want to dynamically build the Tcode return value to get different results based on user inputs on other forms.  Why doesn't it work on the odbc table?  I'd also accept a method that builds a search like

in ('A','C')

or

'A' or 'C'

but I don't know how to implement that using functions.

Edit: Oracle version

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Client drivers 19.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find out why it's happening.  I had two options; one was to use VBA to custom-generate sql for a pass-through query on each run.  I tend to save this for complex queries that make use of special functions on the server.  The solution I went with was to turn the function into a boolean that evaluated the string.  Not the fastest thing for large queries, but ..tradeoffs.

```
Function TCeval(S As String) As Boolean
'usage: in criteria line: TCeval([FIELDNAME])
TCeval = False
If 1 = 1 Then 'replace with actual if evaluations
    If S = "A" Or S = "C" Then TCeval = True
End If
If 1 = 0 Then 'replace
    If S = "B" Then TCeval = True
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I can only help you insofar that ODBC in general isn't the problem.

It works with a Sql Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (
    T varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

linked in Access using the ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, containing the values A,B,C as above.

And this query:

```
SELECT T
FROM foobar
WHERE T Like Tcode()
```

returns the values A+C (with the function defined as in your question).

So it must be a problem of the Oracle ODBC driver.

You should probably specify, which version of Oracle and the ODBC driver you use.

---

Note that you can't use the `IN` clause with a function, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63054220/3820271